# How can I use get/set methods to change in a child object the value of its parent class member variable?

Tags: c++, oop, parent-child

I'm programming a space invaders text game and I'm having some trouble with setting class variable values of parent class in child class object. I want to change Alien_State of an alien object by accessing the alien swarm object that it belongs to.

I have an Alien class:

```
enum class Alien_State {
    AS_ALIVE = 0,
    AS_DEAD,
    AS_EXPLODING
};

class Alien : public StaticObject{
protected:
    Alien_State alienState;
    Alien_Type alienType;
public:
    Alien();
    virtual ~Alien() = default;

    // GET METHODS
    inline Alien_State getAlienState() const { return alienState; }
    inline Alien_Type getAlienType() const { return alienType; }

    // SET METHODS
    inline void setAlienState(const Alien_State alien_state) { alienState = alien_state; }
    inline void setAlienType(const Alien_Type alien_type) { alienType = alien_type; }
};
```

(I don't add StaticObject implementation because it has nothing to do with this question in particular)

And an AlienSwarm class:

```
class AlienSwarm
{
protected:
    Position position;
    std::vector<std::vector<Alien>> aliens;
    int numAliensLeft;
public:
    AlienSwarm();

    // GET METHODS
    inline Position getPosition() const { return position; }
    inline std::vector<std::vector<Alien>> getAliens() const { return aliens; }
    inline int getNumAliensLeft() const { return numAliensLeft; }

    // SET METHODS
    inline void setPosition(const int& x, const int& y) { this->position.x = x; this->position.y = y;
};
```

All Alien in aliens are intialized with alienState {Alien_State::AS_ALIVE};
Then, I want in int main (void) to be able to change its state to AS_DEAD by doing something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    AlienSwarm alien_swarm;
    for (auto& alien_row : alien_swarm.getAliens()) {
        for (auto& alien : alien_row) {
            alien.setAlienState(Alien_State::AS_DEAD); // Example
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can get an Alien_State value of an Alien from alien_swarm by doing: alien_swarm.getAliens().at(0).at(0).getAlienState()
But I don't know how could I do to chain set methods to set an AlienState value.

Thanks in advance for your help, greetings!

Comment: `getAliens` returns a *copy*  of the the member variable. You should be returning a reference instead

Comment: [Unrelated] Add method AlienSwarm::setAliensState(Alien_State alien_state) {
    std::for_each(aliens.begin(), aliens.end(), [alien_state](auto& v){
      std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [alien_state](auto& alien){alien.setAlienState(alien_state);});
    });
  }

Comment: Thanks a lot @UnholySheep ! I didn't think about returning a reference, that's exactly what I needed =)